# C# .NET Uploading file to a web form using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

Does anyone have a working example using HttpWebRequest in C# to submit a file from the local drive to a multipart/form-data web form?

Answer (score 10):

it is WAY easier to do this with WebClient

```
string url = "http://myserver/myapp/upload.aspx";
string file = "c:\\files\\test.jpg";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.UploadFile(url,"post",file);
```

If it needs to be httpwebrequest I can put something together for you (it is possible), but it will be more like 50 lines then 5